# How to enable "Preview" in open/save dialogs (viewed as List)?

Tags: finder, preview, ui, split-view, simbl

I hate open/save dialogs.  They suck.  Specifically, I want the same functionality as...

[image: finder]

here..

[image: open save]

I don't want to use "Browser View", I don't want to use Quicklook.  I **don't mind** a nasty hack.

Any takers?

Answer (score 1):

How about [DefaultFolderX](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/)?
More features than I know what to write about, without it sounding like an advert ;-)
I've used it so long I actually find it difficult to work on machines that don't have it installed.

[image]